# How can I add a c code function to lua file and vice versa

Tags: c, lua

I'm looking for a way to be able to read lua's main function in my c code.

I'm also looking for a way to pass a C function to lua

In my sample code `LoadTBL` would be the function that comes from the C code

```
TBL = 
{
    { Init,     0, 15, 00 },
    { End,      1, 16, 00 }
}

function main()

    for key, value in pairs(TBL) do
        result, msg = LoadTBL(value[1], value[2], value[3]);
        if( not result ) then return false, msg;
        end
    end
        
    return true, "success";
end
```

C code:

```
int LoadTBL (int val1, int val2, int val3) {
    ....
    return 0;
}


void read_test(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("Error 'test.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read complete.\n");

}
```

The idea is to create luas scripts that can interact with C codes

Comment: Please note I've posted an answer below that assumes *"read lua's main function in my c code"* means to load/run the containing file, similar to your example C code, and then be able to execute the `main` function. Otherwise, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720930/2505965) for dumping a function to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to spend more time reading about the [Lua C API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4).

Here is an example of a C program, or *host*, that creates a Lua state, [registers a global function](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_register), and executes a Lua file. Once the file is finished executing, the host program [gets the global Lua value](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_getglobal) `main`, and attempts to call it. If successful, the host [reads the return values](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_tostring) from the stack, and prints them.

Note how the C function is defined as a [`lua_CFunction`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_CFunction), and interacts with the Lua stack.

I'm not sure what you expect this `LoadTBL` function to do, so for demonstration purposes, the one below checks that all its arguments [are integers](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_isinteger) and are evenly divisible.

`main.c`:

```
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void die(lua_State *L, const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_close(L);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int loadTBL(lua_State *L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    int even = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (!lua_isinteger(L, i) || (lua_tointeger(L, i) % 2 != 0)) {
            even = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    lua_pushboolean(L, even);
    lua_pushstring(L, "some message");
    return 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "LoadTBL", loadTBL);

    if (LUA_OK != luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua"))
        die(L, "dofile");

    lua_getglobal(L, "main");

    if (LUA_OK != lua_pcall(L, 0, 2, 0))
        die(L, "calling main");

    printf("GOT <%d>[%s]\n", lua_toboolean(L, -2), lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_close(L);
}
```

`test.lua`:

```lua
local TBL = {
    { 0, 15, 0 },
    { 1, 16, 0 }
}

function main()
    for key, value in pairs(TBL) do
        local result, msg = LoadTBL(value[1], value[2], value[3])

        if not result then
            return false, msg
        end
    end

    return true, "success"
end
```

Comment: Interesting how you did it, I was trying to use `luaL_Reg`, I liked the way you used it

Comment: [`luaL_Reg`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_Reg) is also a perfectly valid way to expose C functions to Lua, though it is usually used when creating a *library* (shared object) - something your Lua programs can [`require`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-require). See [`luaL_newlib`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_newlib) / [`luaL_setfuncs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_setfuncs).