# Lua bytecode to readable

Tags: lua, bytecode

This question seems to have been asked a few times, but I haven't found a clear/useful answer...  I am rather new to coding.  Anyways, I am looking at a game's code in Lua bytecode (I *think*) and am wondering if there is a way to convert it into readable code.

'bytecode' excample(so someone can identify it and better help me):

`loadstring("\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\68`

Thanks!

Comment: This is probable Lua 5.1 bytecode. You can save it to a file and run `luac -l` on it to see its contents. Converting it to Lua source code is not trivial. There are some tools that do a partial job, such as luadec, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best tool(s) for decompiling Lua bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743684/best-tools-for-decompiling-lua-bytecode)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [luadec51](https://github.com/sztupy/luadec51) tool for decompiling lua versions 5.1.x.

Download release file from [here](https://github.com/sztupy/luadec51/releases') and run the command:
`Luadec51 compiled_script.lua(c) > decompiled_new_file.lua`

It'll decompile the lua(c) file into a readable text file.

---

Note: there's also a fork of luadec51 to decompile lua 5.1 , 5.2 and 5.3: https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec but as of now there's no binary so you have to compile it first to make it work.

---

source: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools

---

**Update:** I found a tool for compiling/decompiling/comparing lua files: [LuaTool 1.2 - Lua Decompiler, Compiler and Compare](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=568281)