# How to unscape bytecode which contains strings

Tags: reverse-engineering, bytecode, ctf

I m new to reverse engineering and I was solving a CTF, I did find the byte code but it seems like I should sanitize it(it contains some strings), and unescape it properly.
Here is a chunk of the byte code.
`\x1bLuaS\x00\x19\x93\r\n\x1a\n\x04\x08\x04\x08\x08xV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(w@\x01\r@unknown.lua\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x03\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x80&\x00\x80\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x06check\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\t\xbf\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00_\x00\xc0\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x00\x01\x00d\x80\x80\x01_@\xc1\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x80\x01\x00d\x80\x80\x01_\xc0\xc1\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x00\x02\x00d\x80\x80\x01_@\xc2\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x80\x02\x00d\x80\x80\x01_\xc0\xc2\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x00\x03\x00d\x80\x80\x01_@\xc3\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x01F\x80@\x00G\xc0\xc0\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x80\x03\x00d\x80\x80\x01_\xc0\xc3\x00\x1e@\x00\x80A@\x00` ...

Comment: If you just want to convert this into a hex dump, you can do this on the command line. In Linux, for example, try `echo -ne '\x1bLuaS\x00\x19\x93\r\n\x1a\n\x04\x08\x04\x08\x08xV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(w@\x01\r@unknown.lua\x00' | xxd`. But in any case, this is clearly Lua bytecode, which is already discussed in another question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua bytecode to readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321388/lua-bytecode-to-readable)