# Lua string decompiler

Tags: lua, binary, chunks

Is it possible to de obfuscate this string to make it readable?

I have tried unluac and luadec but its impossible.

```
local data =('1B4C7561520000040404080019930D0A1A0A00000000000000000001120000038700000025800000080000402580800008000080010000C041000080818000802100410106000141410100411D7FFEC020004180060041C007000200410200008B000080C100024101000281410002C181020040A4008000C3000001030400014B00034181000381C10003C2010004024100044281000482C10004C301000503410400416486014008004301460001418B8B45C18A8C46418A8D46C18A8E47418A8F40818A8A81814A004301460001C18B8B47C18A8C46418A8D46C18A9040818A004181C603C881C79081C18..{other bunch of codes}')
local chunk = data:gsub('..', function (c) return string.char(tonumber(c, 16)) end)
local func = load(chunk)
func()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best tool(s) for decompiling Lua bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743684/best-tools-for-decompiling-lua-bytecode)

Comment: *Which* Lua? 5.1? 5.2? 5.3? LuaJIT? Some other weird implementation?

Comment: The header shows 'LUAR', it must be lua 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *almost* lua bytecode, it's just obfuscated a bit more: each char is encoded as hex. Easy way to get bytecode is

```
local data = 'your lovely data'
local f = assert(io.open('bytecode.luac', 'wb'))
for c in data:gmatch('..') do
    f:write(string.char(tonumber(c, 16)))
end
f:flush()
f:close()
```

This will write bytecode to `bytecode.luac`. Now you need actual decompilation: https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec looks like a great tool here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I was able to convert it into bytecode.luac but failed in decompilation. Luadec, chunkspy, unluac nothing seems to work. It's lua 5.2.

Comment: @Rico Have you compiled luadec with lua5.2 flags?

Comment: Also, does `loadfile('bytecode.lua')` succeed in lua? Try different lua versions, working one should be bytecode version.

Comment: No, I haven't tried but  I'll keep trying. Thank You.